# How do you expose a global javascript function without ESLint no-unused-var error?

Tags: javascript, closures, eslint

The following code is valid in ESLint with Google's style guide with one exception; the closure function `Counter` gets a `no-unused-vars` error when the script is checked using ESLint.

```
/**
 * Create a counter that is incremented and returned when called
 * @return {object} - incrementor function
 */
function Counter() {
  var _i = 0;

  /**
   * increment counter
   * @return {int} - The incremented integer
   */
  function _incrementor() {
    _i++;
    return _i;
  }

  _incrementor.incr = function() {
    this.call();
    return _incrementor;
  };

  _incrementor.val = function(val) {
    if (!arguments.length) { return _i; }
    _i = val;
    return _incrementor;
  };

  return _incrementor;
}
```

I would like to have this function (or one structure the same way) as a standalone script that I can include in my HTML and then call from a different script like so:

```
var count = Counter()
    .val(5);

count.incr() 
console.log(count.val())  // prints => 6
```

I have tried including `/* exported Counter */` at the top of the script but the error persists. How do I silence/fix this error?

Comment: According to [eslint.org](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.html) adding `/* export Counter */` should have worked, unless it's specifically for variables and not standalone functions. Also, closure is kind of irrelevant here since it's not an IIFE.

Comment: IIFE?

In reality, I'm using functions like this to create reusable D3 chart generators. This is just a simple example.

Comment: Why no just put `//eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars` to ignore the error. And here is the description on when `exported` will not work http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars.html#exporting-variables

Comment: Disabling the line works to suppress the error, but I'd rather just fix it properly if possible. I have double checked that the node and commonjs environment options in my .eslintrc are false and that ecmaFeatures.modules is also false but still get the error.

Comment: I created the scenario locally what you have and I was not able to reproduce the issue. I used eslint 1.10.3. I made sure I didnt have node and commenjs or modules setup.
Can you move this code into a separate file and run eslint on this directly?

Comment: Moved the script to a new file and a new location. I ran `eslint --init` and chose the google style guide. My .eslintrc.js file looks like this:
    
`module.exports = {
  ecmaFeatures: {
    modules: false
  },
  env: {
    node: false,
    commonjs: false
  },
  extends: 'google'
};`

The error is still there. When you tried it, did you do a `eslint --init`? Perhaps it's something in the google defaults that is triggering the error

Comment: Did u add `/* exported Counter */` on top of the file? whats the eslint version?

Comment: Yes I did. Using version 1.10.3. Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: Trying running with `--debug` flag to see the correct `.eslintrc` files are getting picked up. Also look for any other red flags. Also can u share the exact file you are trying to lint using fiddle. The new file where you moved the script to. that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly adding Counter to the global scope silences this error and prevents errors that may occur as a result of the implicit global scope used in the question.

```js
/**
 * Create a counter that is incremented and returned when called
 * @return {object} - incrementor function
 */
this.Counter = function() {
  var _i = 0;

  /**
   * increment counter
   * @return {int} - The incremented integer
   */
  function _incrementor() {
    _i++;
    return _i;
  }

  _incrementor.incr = function() {
    this.call();
    return _incrementor;
  };

  _incrementor.val = function(val) {
    if (!arguments.length) {
      return _i;
    }
    _i = val;
    return _incrementor;
  };

  return _incrementor;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some options for telling the linter to allow a global Counter variable:

**Option #1**: Add this comment to the top of the js file when you need to use the global variable:

```
/* globals Counter */
```

**Option #2:** Add the variable name to the globals property in your eslint configuration file:

```
// eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  // ...

  globals: {
    'Counter': true
  }
}
```

See [ESLint documentation here](http://eslint.org/docs/1.0.0/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) for more info.

*Note: you can also use the `env` property in your config file for predefined sets of globals like: browser (ie. localStorage), jquery, node, etc.). See* [here](http://eslint.org/docs/1.0.0/user-guide/configuring#specifying-environments).