# Load environment variables into vue.js

Tags: environment-variables, vue.js

I am building an app using node.js + vue.js and was wondering if anyone knows how I can load environment variables into my vue.js components? Right now I'm loading environment variables in my server side code using the `dotenv` package but it doesn't seem to work for vue.js..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use [DefinePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/), check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43508655/4305494). You can also use DefinePlugin along with [Configuration types](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/) like in this other [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41900834/4305494).

Answer (score 6):

You can expose environment variables from NodeJS like this:

```
console.log(process.env.EXAMPLE_VARIABLE);
```

More details on `process.env`: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env

To expose your environment variables to the client-side in Vue (or any Javascript framework for that matter), you could render a JSON response from NodeJS that is ingested via an AJAX call.

Comment: You can only the environment variables after you close the dev server and restart,  or do a new build~

Comment: I just restarted like @mintedsky suggested and it worked.  `npm run serve` - thanks

Comment: Because of Vue CLI 3, future viewers might benefit from this post instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828904/using-environment-variables-with-vue-js

Answer (score 3):

Using `Vue Cli 3`, You can load your environment variables like this

1. Create a `.env` file in the root directory of your application.
2. In the `.env` file, prefix your environment variables with `VUE_APP_`.

   Example: `VUE_APP_SECRET=SECRET`.
3. Now you can access them with `process.env.THE_NAME_OF_THE_VARIABLE` in your application code.

   Example: `console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET)` `// SECRET`

You can read more [here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#modes)

Comment: when I do this, the value getting printed in console is 'SECRET' and not the value of SECRET set from express node.js

Comment: PLEASE, do not put actual secrests into the .env file, it will get exposed.