# How to determine the installed webpack version

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, webpack-2, webpack-3

Especially during the transition from webpack v1 to v2, it would be important to programmatically determine what [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) version is installed, but I cannot seem to find the appropriate API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

webpack 4 now offers a version property that can be used!

Comment: What this means is that wherever you have the `webpack` variable provided (like in your setup/config file) you can just call `webpack.version` and you'll get back a version string of the form `"x.y.z"`.

Answer (score 202):

### Version Installed:

Using [**webpack CLI**](https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/): `(--version, -v  Show version number [boolean])`

```
webpack --version
```

or:

```
webpack -v
```

Using [**npm list**](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls) command:

```
npm list webpack
```

Results in `name@version-range`:

```
<projectName>@<projectVersion> /path/to/project
└── webpack@<version-range>
```

Using [**yarn list**](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/list/#toc-yarn-list) command:

```
yarn list webpack
```

---

### How to do it programmatically?

Webpack 2 introduced [**Configuration Types**](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/configuration-types/).

> Instead of exporting a configuration object, you may return a function
>   which accepts an environment as argument. When running webpack, you
>   may specify build environment keys via `--env`, such as `--env.production`
>   or `--env.platform=web`.

We will use a build environment key called `--env.version`.

```
webpack --env.version $(webpack --version)
```

or:

```
webpack --env.version $(webpack -v)
```

For this to work we will need to do two things:

Change our `webpack.config.js` file and use [**DefinePlugin**](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/).

> The DefinePlugin allows you to create global constants which can be
>   configured at compile time.

```
-module.exports = {
+module.exports = function(env) {
+  return {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
+        WEBPACK_VERSION: JSON.stringify(env.version) //<version-range>
      })
    ]
+  };
};
```

Now we can access the global constant like so:

```
console.log(WEBPACK_VERSION);
```

---

### Latest version available:

Using [**npm view**](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/view) command will return the latest version available on the registry:

> `npm view [<@scope>/]<name>[@<version>] [<field>[.<subfield>]...]`

---

For webpack use:

```
npm view webpack version
```

Comment: So webpack has no API that returns it's version and I have to use a shell command?

Comment: this works fine via the cli.... but how would one do this programmatically? (aka: inside a script file)

Comment: I have included a way to programmatically extract webpack's version and use it as a global constant inside any file.

Comment: well, I had to type `npx webpack --version`

Comment: @doberkofler has the (now correct) answer, and it's even marked as the right answer! https://stackoverflow.com/a/52143627/3221576

You can't rely on `webpack -v` because that assumes your current shell's `webpack` is the same as what's running in your program.

Answer (score 25):

Just another way not mentioned yet:

If you installed it locally to a project then open up the node_modules folder and check your webpack module.

`< /node_modules/webpack/package.json`

Open the package.json file and look under version

[image]

Answer (score 23):

For those who are using `yarn`

`yarn list webpack` will do the trick

```
$ yarn list webpack
yarn list v0.27.5
└─ webpack@2.6.1
Done in 1.24s.
```

Answer (score 9):

If using Angular CLI v7+, the webpack version is printed in the output of `ng version`:

```
-> ng version

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 7.0.6
Node: 11.0.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 7.1.0
... animations, cdk, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.10.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.10.6
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.10.6
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.10.6
@angular-devkit/core              7.0.6
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.0.6
@angular/cli                      7.0.6
@ngtools/webpack                  7.0.6
@schematics/angular               7.0.6
@schematics/update                0.10.6
rxjs                              6.3.3
typescript                        3.1.6
webpack                           4.19.1
```

Comment: In angular 10, webpack is not listed with `ng version`. If you're using custom webpack config with `@angular-builders/custom-webpack`, try `npm list webpack`, it showed me the used version of webpack.

Answer (score 5):

In CLI

```
$ webpack --version
    
webpack-cli 4.1.0
    
webpack 5.3.2
```

In Code (node runtime)

```
process.env.npm_package_devDependencies_webpack // ^5.3.2
```

or

```
process.env.npm_package_dependencies_webpack // ^5.3.2
```

In Plugin

```
compiler.webpack.version // 5.3.2
```

Answer (score 4):

Put `webpack -v` into your **package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack -v",
    "dev": "webpack --watch"
  }
}
```

Then enter in the console:

```
npm run build
```

Expected output should look like:

```
> npm run build

> js@1.0.0 build /home/user/repositories/myproject/js
> webpack -v

4.42.0
```

Answer (score -2):

npm webpack --version

works for me and it throws something like:

PS C:\Users\alfon\OneDrive\Escritorio\sandbox\fimusicv4\with-redux-app> npm webpack --version
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
**8.5.5**

Comment: FYI This ignores the webpack parameter and prints your npm version.

Comment: `npm run webpack --version`