# How to determine the installed version of webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I'm building something with Webpack to transpile and bundle few JS files. However, I'd like to know which version I'm using.

Let's suppose that I have the it installed globally. How would I do it without checking `package.json`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661383/how-to-determine-the-installed-webpack-version/41900834

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Due to my reputation, I am unable to comment. But quickly wanted to point out as suggested above in the right answer:

> Alternate method:
>
> `npm view webpack version`

will only show the latest `webpack` that is **available to download** from the registry. It will not show the installed version.

(without dependencies)

For globally installed packages: `npm list -g --depth=0`

For locally installed packages: `npm list --depth=0`

(with dependencies)

For globally installed packages: `npm list -g`

For locally installed packages: `npm list`

Source: 
[Find the version of an installed npm package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972176/find-the-version-of-an-installed-npm-package)

Answer (score 7):

Run `npm list --depth=0` and you will see a list of global modules with version listed. They're in alphabetical order so you should see `webpack` at the very end. In my case it reads `webpack-core@1.14.0`.

Comment: `npm view webpack version` will only show the latest webpack that is available to download from the registry. It will not show the installed version.