# How to check webpacker version in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

How can I find `webpacker` version in my `rails 6` application through the terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine the installed webpack version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41661383/how-to-determine-the-installed-webpack-version)

Comment: This does not work. Webpack and webpacker are two different things. Check this out - https://stackshare.io/stackups/webpack-vs-webpacker

Comment: `bundle list webpacker` ?

Comment: This is not working

Comment: What does it say when you run the bundle command?

Comment: ERROR: "bundle list" was called with arguments ["webpacker"]
Usage: "bundle list"
This is the error.

Comment: check this command : *npm list webpack*

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
bundle list | grep webpack
```

Result:

```
* webpacker (5.4.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the **package.json** file in the project root foler.