# How to use dotenv with Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to add some environment variables into my vue app.

here is content of my `.env` file, which is placed on root(outside `src`):

```
VUE_APP_GOODREADS_KEY = my_key
```

and I added code for dot env on the top of my `main.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'

import dotenv from 'dotenv'

dotenv.config()

import { router } from './router'
import store from './store'
```

I want to use this variable within my store `./store/index.js`

I tried to console.log environment variables within store but no luck:

```
console.log(process.env)
```

But all I'm getting is

```
NODE_ENV:"development"
```

Only related thread I found was [Load environment variables into vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39426214/load-environment-variables-into-vue-js), but it only mentions how to use existing variables in the `process.env`. I want to add environment variables using dotenv. Why this code is not working?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

If your project was create by using `Vue CLI 3`, no need to use `dotenv` to get environment variables.

To get environment variables within `.env` file in your project:

1. Placing the `.env` file in your project root.
2. In the `.env` file, specifying environment variables with "VUE_APP_" prefix.

   `VUE_APP_SOMEKEY=SOME_KEY_VALUE`.
3. Finally, you can access them with `process.env.*` in your application code.

   `console.log(process.env.VUE_APP_SOMEKEY)  // SOME_KEY_VALUE`

Referance: [Vue CLI 3 - Environment Variables and Modes](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#using-env-variables-in-client-side-code)

Comment: What if I want to use `dotenv`?

Comment: @PrestonDocks Vue CLI 3 !== Vue Js 3, Vue CLI 3 generates Vue Js 2.x code, VueJS 3 is the next version of vue that's not out yet.

Answer (score 7):

When using Vue CLI 2, you have to use the dev.env.js and prod.env.js files located in the config folder.

Vue CLI 2 does not support the use of .env files, however [Vue CLI 3 does](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables).

```
// /config/prod.env.js
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"production"',
  SERVER_URI: "http://someremoteuri:3333/api/v1"
}
```

```
// /config/dev.env.js
'use strict'
module.exports = {
  NODE_ENV: '"development"',
  SERVER_URI: "http://localhost:3333/api/v1"
}
```

Comment: Vue CLI 3 !== Vue Js 3, Vue CLI 3 generates Vue Js 2.x code, VueJS 3 is the next version of vue that's not out yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the spaces around the equal sign.

```
VUE_APP_GOODREADS_KEY=my_key
```

Also, try debugging like this:

```
const config = dotenv.config()
if(config.error){
  console.log('Could not load env file', config.error)
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#config

Comment: It seems I cant use it in the client side as it throws an error `fs not defined`.

Comment: Well, that is expected. How can a browser read an arbitrary file on your server? `fs` is a node builtin. However, you can setup a route which serves the config as a JSON string, so the browser can fetch and parse that

Comment: Can you explain the set up a bit? I didn't get the method.