# AWS SAM CLI Unit testing Lambda Functions NodeJS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, mocha.js, aws-sam

I am using the [SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install.html) to test and deploy AWS Lambda functions. I am trying to run unit tests using Mocha and Chai in NodeJS. The tests are located in the `test` directory and I can run the tests using the command `mocha --recursive`.

The problem is I am using environment variables in the tests. My environemnt variables are defined in the   `template.yaml` file for the SAM CLI. It looks something like this:

```
  RefreshFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/index.handler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Environment:
        Variables:
          APP_ID: A
          CLIENT_ID: B 
          CLIENT_SECRET: C 
          AWS_REGION_DB: D
```

They are defined here as when I deploy my function they automatically go with it onto AWS too. It also allows me to use the `sam local invoke` command which runs my lambda function locally using Docker.

Is there anyway that anyone knows that the `sam local invoke` command can be used to run test cases locally instaed of running the lambda function? Or how to access my environment variables in the `template.yaml` file from test cases using mocha and chai?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decided to update this answer as a few people have bookmarked this question.

To get the same setup I have to start with run `sam init`, select the `AWS Quick Start Templates`, the run time is `nodejs12.x` and the application template to use is `Quick Start: From Scratch`.

After this step you should have a directory structure that looks like this below in your sam application.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user 9596 Apr  9 12:02 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 4 user 4096 Apr  9 12:02 __tests__
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user 828  Apr  9 12:02 buildspec.yml
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user 374  Apr  9 12:02 package.json
drwxr-xr-x 3 user 4096 Apr  9 12:02 src
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user 1545 Apr  9 12:02 template.yml
```

Run an `npm install` to install the dependecies which creates your `node_modules` directory.
After this has finished run the following command to install the `dotenv` module.

```
npm install dotenv
```

Create a file named `.env` in the root directory. Your root directory should now look like this.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1   user 9596   Apr  9 12:02 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 4   user 4096   Apr  9 12:02 __tests__
-rwxr-xr-x 1   user 828    Apr  9 12:02 buildspec.yml
drwxr-xr-x 391 user 16384  Apr  9 12:05 node_modules
-rw-r--r-- 1   user 488688 Apr  9 12:05 package-lock.json
-rwxr-xr-x 1   user 374    Apr  9 12:02 package.json
drwxr-xr-x 3   user 4096   Apr  9 12:02 src
-rwxr-xr-x 1   user 1545   Apr  9 12:02 template.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1   user 28     Apr  9 11:06 .env
```

Now in your `.env` file create an environment variable like my sample one below.

```
TEST_ENV_VAR=HELLO_FROM_TEST
```

In your `template.yml` file also define an environment variable of the same name but give it a different value so we can see when the two different locations are being read in the next step.

```
helloFromLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: src/handlers/hello-from-lambda.helloFromLambdaHandler
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 100
      Description: A Lambda function that returns a static string.
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      Environment:
        Variables:
          TEST_ENV_VAR: Hello_From_Local_Invoke #HERE WE ARE DEFINING ENV VARS
```

In the handler file located at `src/handlers/hello-from-lambda.js` change the code to the following which is reading in the environment varibale `TEST_ENV_VAR` and returning it.

```
exports.helloFromLambdaHandler = async () => {
    // Read in the environment variable 
    const message = process.env.TEST_ENV_VAR
    // Log the environment variable out 
    console.info(`${message}`);
    // Return the environment variable so we can verify value in test case 
    return message;
}
```

In your test handler located at `__tests__/unit/handlers/hello-from-lambda.test.js` paste the following code. It reads the environment variables from the `.env` you created earlier using the `dotenv` module. The test will now pass if the value returned from the `helloFromLambdaHandler`  is equal to the value `HELLO_FROM_TEST` which is the value we defined for the environment variable `TEST_ENV_VAR` in the `.env` file.

```
// Import all functions from hello-from-lambda.js
const lambda = require('../../../src/handlers/hello-from-lambda.js');
require('dotenv').config(); // HERE WE ARE USING THE dotenv MODULE 

// This includes all tests for helloFromLambdaHandler()
describe('Test for hello-from-lambda', function () {
    // This test invokes helloFromLambdaHandler() and compare the result 
    it('Verifies successful response', async () => {
        // Invoke helloFromLambdaHandler()
        const result = await lambda.helloFromLambdaHandler();
        // The expected result should match the return from your Lambda function.
        // We expect it to be HELLO_FROM_TEST as thats what is in our .env file for the variable TEST_ENV_VAR
        const expectedResult = 'HELLO_FROM_TEST';
        // Compare the result with the expected result
        expect(result).toEqual(expectedResult);
    });
});
```

Now run the test by running the command `npm run test` in the root directory, it passes showing that we are reading from the `.env` for test cases.

```
$ npm run test

> replaced-by-user-input@0.0.1 test
> jest --roots __tests__/unit

 PASS  __tests__/unit/handlers/hello-from-lambda.test.js
  Test for hello-from-lambda
    ✓ Verifies successful response (12 ms)

  console.info
    HELLO_FROM_TEST

      at Object.helloFromLambdaHandler (src/handlers/hello-from-lambda.js:5:13)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.919 s, estimated 1 s
Ran all test suites.
```

To prove we are reading from the `template.yml` file for production builds you can invoke a local test by running `sam build` to build the project and then `sam local invoke` all from the root directory.

```
$ sam local invoke
Invoking src/handlers/hello-from-lambda.helloFromLambdaHandler (nodejs12.x)
Skip pulling image and use local one: amazon/aws-sam-cli-emulation-image-nodejs12.x:rapid-1.12.0.

Mounting /home/warren/lambda/new_test/sam-app/.aws-sam/build/helloFromLambdaFunction as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 4de19569-5ebc-1c20-1cec-9a290dd3ef9b Version: $LATEST
2021-04-09T11:29:40.993Z        4de19569-5ebc-1c20-1cec-9a290dd3ef9b    INFO    Hello_From_Local_Invoke
END RequestId: 4de19569-5ebc-1c20-1cec-9a290dd3ef9b
REPORT RequestId: 4de19569-5ebc-1c20-1cec-9a290dd3ef9b  Init Duration: 187.97 ms        Duration: 6.80 ms       Billed Duration: 100 ms                                Memory Size: 128 MB      Max Memory Used: 48 MB

"Hello_From_Local_Invoke"
```

You can see we now get the value `Hello_From_Local_Invoke` which is the value we assigned to the environment variable `TEST_ENV_VAR` in the `template.yml` file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you please add the steps to create the .env file (location, format) and how to use it when running the test?

Comment: @AndresaMartins try [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715302/how-to-use-dotenv-with-vue-js)

Answer (score 0):

I found out another way of doing it. You can set the environment variable in your own local machine:

MacOS:

```
export APP_ID=A
```

Windows:

```
SET APP_ID=A
```

Then just run your tests using mocha as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Environment variables are meant to be defined in your environment. You would use other tools like `dotenv` if you wanted to run locally but change some/all of the environment variables. You can also put these in your `package.json` in the `scripts` section with `FOO=BAR`. As long as there are no secrets in there that will be safe to do.