# Using Environment Variables with Vue.js

Tags: node.js, vue.js, environment-variables, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I've been reading the official docs and I'm unable to find anything on environment variables. Apparently there are some community projects that support environment variables but this might be overkill for me. So I was wondering if there's something simple out of the box that works natively when working on a project already created with Vue CLI.

For example, I can see that if I do the following the right environment prints out meaning this is already setup?

```
mounted() {
  console.log(process.env.ROOT_API)
}
```

I'm a kinda new to env variables and Node.

FYI using Vue CLI version 3.0 beta.

Comment: Which vue-cli template are you using? If Webpack, see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/env.html

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you're asking. Do you have an actual question?

Comment: if you are using Webpack. yes `process.env` works for getting environment variables.

Comment: I created my project with `vue create my-app` and `env` variables aren't working as per the docs you posted @Phil

Comment: You must prefix variable with ' VUE_APP_' https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#example-staging-mode

Answer (score 311, accepted):

**Vue.js with Webpack**

If you use vue cli with the Webpack template (default config), you can create and add your environment variables to a .env file.

The variables will automatically be accessible under `process.env.variableName` in your project. Loaded variables are also available to all vue-cli-service commands, plugins and dependencies.

You have a few options, this is from the [Environment Variables and Modes documentation](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html):

```
.env                # loaded in all cases
.env.local          # loaded in all cases, ignored by git
.env.[mode]         # only loaded in specified mode
.env.[mode].local   # only loaded in specified mode, ignored by git
```

Your .env file should look like this:

```
VUE_APP_MY_ENV_VARIABLE=value
VUE_APP_ANOTHER_VARIABLE=value
```

**As noted in comment below:**
If you are using Vue cli 3, only variables that start with **VUE_APP_** will be loaded.

Don't forget to restart *serve* if it is currently running.

**Vue.js with Vite**

Vite exposes env variables that start with `VITE_` on the special `import.meta.env` object.

Your .env should look like this:

```
VITE_API_ENDPOINT=value
VITE_API_KEY=value
```

These variables can be accessed in Vue.js components or JavaScript files under `import.meta.env.VITE_API_ENDPOINT` and `import.meta.env.VITE_API_KEY`.

**Tip:** Remember to restart your development server whenever you change or add a variable in the .env file if it's running.

For more info, please see the [Vite documentation for env variables](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html).

Comment: Thanks will give it a try. Yes my project was created with the native Vue CLI, as per the docs.

Comment: with `vue create my-app`

Comment: Important to note: *Only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin.*

Comment: can I still use `.env` file without using the vue-cli?

Comment: **Only variables that start with `VUE_APP_` will be statically embedded**  
which means that if you want to have env-vars accessible on the client side code, then you must use `VUE_APP_` as prefix for keys in `.env` files

Comment: Yap, just like I explained below a few months ago in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51745622/9661304. Upvotes are appreciated :D

Comment: Don't forget to restart **serve** if it is currently running.

Comment: yes, the docs said .env.[mode] it means any [mode] like 'dev' or 'prod' should works, but, by default it uses env.development and env.production so when you npm run serve it will use env.development and not .env.dev

Comment: How is it acceptable that Vue enforces the need of prefixing with `VUE_APP_` for environment variables? I've just started implementing our environment variables and already come across an injected environment variable in prod that I can't change, so now I have to watch for both the local `VUE_APP_` prefixed and the production non-prefixed versions.

Comment: Important to note: We need to prefix all env variables with `VUE_APP_`, except for the `NODE_ENV` and `BASE_URL`.

Comment: Thank you for "only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be loaded.".

Comment: VUE_APP_ -> this. wasted over 30 minutes of my time. ty.

Comment: As other answers helpfully point out, make sure you place your .env files at the root of the project, as a sibling of package.json (not in the src folder, for example).

Comment: What about another answer stating that the file name .env.production will be used with build ? Is that correct or will .env be used with build ?

Comment: I am using vite. There env variables must start with VITE_ and don't need to install dotenv. instead process use import.meta.env.VITE_env_variable. here is documentation https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html

Answer (score 123):

If you are using Vue cli 3, only variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be loaded.

In the root create a .env file with:

```
VUE_APP_ENV_VARIABLE=value
```

And, if it's running, you need to restart *serve* so that the new env vars can be loaded.

With this, you will be able to use process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_VARIABLE in your project (.js and .vue files).

#### Update

According to @ali6p, with Vue Cli 3, isn't necessary to install dotenv dependency.

Comment: Doesn't need to add any code to main.js, just use `process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_VARIABLE` Isn't it?

Comment: you need to install dotenv if you don't have and then just use it like that.

Comment: If the project is created by using Vue CLI 3, no need to use dotenv to get environment variables. Maybe you'd like to add this case to your answer.

Comment: Just need to use process.env.VUE_APP_ENV_VARIABLE? Is that true?

Comment: Yes. After CLI 3

Comment: And don't forget to rebuild your project.

Comment: Where should be put the .env file ? In the src directory ?

Comment: It should be on the root of the project, like the package.json

Comment: Restarting the server also helped. Is adding the `VUE_APP` piece documented anywhere?

Answer (score 105):

1. Create two files in root folder (near by package.json) `.env` and `.env.production`
2. Add variables to theese files with prefix `VUE_APP_` eg:  `VUE_APP_WHATEVERYOUWANT`
3. **serve** uses `.env` and **build** uses `.env.production`
4. In your components (vue or js), use `process.env.VUE_APP_WHATEVERYOUWANT` to call value
5. Don't forget to restart **serve** if it is currently running
6. Clear browser cache

***Be sure you are using vue-cli version 3 or above***

For more information: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html

Comment: This should be the only answer to this really nasty issue. Thank you! Pointing out where the root folder is and point 5 and 6 differentiate this from the rest of the answers. Also you need to install dotenv: npm install dotenv, I think. Well done.

Comment: Always forgetting to restart the server!

Comment: when you say 'restart serve', are you referring to web server?

Comment: @Nguaial I mean, re-run the serve script `npm run serve`... or different cmd that depends on your setup.

Comment: This is the best answer here, to be honest. I didn't even need an `.env.development` like other recommended here, just use `.env` as my dev configuration file.

Comment: Must the .env file be created in the src directory or the root directory ?

Comment: @chmike the root directory

Comment: Thanks. Worked also for vue 4. Im having e.g. also .env.test for build my vue app for our test machine. Need to build it with `npm run build -- --mode test`, then it takes the correct file (I think .env + .env.test in combination). Furthermore: If you would like to use env-vars in your template, of course you need to put them into a data attribute like `data(){ return { ENV: process.env } }`
and use them in template, e.g. `This is my env: {{ ENV.VUE_APP_WHATEVERYOUWANT }}`. Or is there any other smooth way?

Answer (score 47):

In the root of your project create your environment files:

- .env
- .env.someEnvironment1
- .env.SomeEnvironment2

To then load those configs, you would specify the environment via `mode` i.e.

```
npm run serve --mode development //default mode
npm run serve --mode someEnvironment1
```

In your `env` files you simply declare the config as key-value pairs, but if you're using vue 3, you **must** prefix with `VUE_APP_`:

In your **.env**:

```
VUE_APP_TITLE=This will get overwritten if more specific available
```

**.env.someEnvironment1:**

```
VUE_APP_TITLE=My App (someEnvironment1)
```

You can then use this in any of your components via:

**myComponent.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div> 
    {{title}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      title: process.env.VUE_APP_TITLE
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Now if you ran the app without a `mode` it will show the 'This will get...' but if you specify a `someEnvironment1` as your `mode` then you will get the title from there.

You can create configs that are 'hidden' from git by appending `.local` to your file: `.env.someEnvironment1.local` - very useful for when you have secrets.

Read [the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html) for more info.

Comment: this is the only answer that worked for me . us the full variable name ...` title: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL `

Comment: Same, this was the only way I could get it work. Once I added the file, ran npm run serve in the root of my projects directory I was able to reference the env variables.

Comment: This is great, one thing to keep in mind is that the "build" mode is different from the webpack `NODE_ENV` mode, so you can use this to setup modes like `staging` or even different "versions" or "deployments" of your application https://medium.com/rangle-io/custom-build-modes-with-vue-cli-3-16ab208b4bc3

Answer (score 13):

A problem I was running into was that **I was using the webpack-simple install** for VueJS which didn't seem to include an Environment variable config folder. So I wasn't able to edit the env.test,development, and production.js config files. Creating them didn't help either.

Other answers weren't detailed enough for me, so I just "fiddled" with webpack.config.js. And the following worked just fine.

So to get Environment Variables to work, the webpack.config.js should have the following at the bottom:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}
```

Based on the above, **in production**, you would be able to get the NODE_ENV variable

```
mounted() {
  console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)
}
```

Now there may be better ways to do this, but if you want to use Environment Variables in Development you would do something like the following:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"development"'
      }
    })
  ]);

}
```

Now if you want to add other variables with would be as simple as:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"development"',
        ENDPOINT: '"http://localhost:3000"',
        FOO: "'BAR'"
      }
    })
  ]);
}
```

**I should also note that you seem to need the "''" double quotes for some reason.**

So, **in Development**, I can now access these Environment Variables:

```
mounted() {
  console.log(process.env.ENDPOINT)
  console.log(process.env.FOO)
}
```

Here is the whole webpack.config.js just for some context:

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    filename: 'build.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ],
      },      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
          // other vue-loader options go here
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]?[hash]'
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    },
    extensions: ['*', '.js', '.vue', '.json']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,
    overlay: true
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false
  },
  devtool: '#eval-source-map'
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  module.exports.devtool = '#source-map'
  // http://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/workflow/production.html
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"production"'
      }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      sourceMap: true,
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
      minimize: true
    })
  ])
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {

  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"development"',
        ENDPOINT: '"http://localhost:3000"',
        FOO: "'BAR'"
      }
    })
  ]);

}
```

Comment: I'm moving toward's Vue CLI 3 for future projects, but ran into the same problem on an App I built with the `webpack-simple` install. I expanded on your logic a little bit here and just created an "else" condition in which I just pass the `process.env.NODE_ENV` value into the DefinePlugin args.

Comment: Aaron McKeehan, I did the same addition to my webpack.config as you advised. But, how can I use that variable I wrote for development in my vue component for request beginning?

Comment: @Aaron McKeehan 
For example, I added, 
`if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  module.exports.plugins = (module.exports.plugins || []).concat([
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: '"development"',
        DEBUG_MODE: true,
        ROOT_API: '"http://localhost:8080/"'
      }
    })
  ]);

}`  and in Setting.vue I want to add this ROOT_API variable in my post request:  axios
        .post(`ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_HERE??/api/users/me/change-password`){...}. Please give me advice, I'm not pro in how webpack works

Comment: The key for me was prefixing with `VUE_APP_` in both `.env` AND in the `file.vue`

Comment: "Note that because the plugin does a direct text replacement, the value given to it must include actual quotes inside of the string itself. Typically, this is done either with alternate quotes, such as '"production"', or by using JSON.stringify('production')." https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/#usage

Answer (score 5):

This is how I edited my `vue.config.js` so that I could expose `NODE_ENV` to the frontend (I'm using Vue-CLI):

**vue.config.js**

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

// options: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/docs/config.md
module.exports = {
    // default baseUrl of '/' won't resolve properly when app js is being served from non-root location
    baseUrl: './',
    outputDir: 'dist',
    configureWebpack: {
        plugins: [
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
                // allow access to process.env from within the vue app
                'process.env': {
                    NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
                }
            })
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for a very long time. It is simple and understandable to throw values into variables from the command line at startup and later can be used in the application. Without additional libraries and difficulties. Thank you very much! Add for the same as me:

1. `CUSTOM_VAR: JSON.stringify (process.env.CUSTOM_VAR) || "default value"`

2. Setting the variable value at run: `set CUSTOM_VAR=value && npm run serve`

3. Use the variable in the application: `console.log (process.env.CUSTOM_VAR)`

Answer (score 3):

In vue-cli version 3:

There are the three options for .env files:
Either you can use `.env` or:

- `.env.test`
- `.env.development`
- `.env.production`

You can use custom `.env` variables by using the prefix regex as `/^/` instead of `/^VUE_APP_/` in `/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/util/resolveClientEnv.js:prefixRE`

This is certainly not recommended for the sake of developing an open source app in different modes like test, development, and production of `.env` files. Because every time you `npm install ..` , it will be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the previous answers, if you're looking to access VUE_APP_* env variables in your sass (either the sass section of a vue component or a scss file), then you can add the following to your vue.config.js (which you may need to create if you don't have one):

```
let sav = "";
for (let e in process.env) {
    if (/VUE_APP_/i.test(e)) {
        sav += `$${e}: "${process.env[e]}";`;
    }
}

module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            sass: {
                data: sav,
            },
        },
    },
}
```

The string sav seems to be prepended to every sass file that before processing, which is fine for variables.  You could also import mixins at this stage to make them available for the sass section of each vue component.

You can then use these variables in your sass section of a vue file:

```
<style lang="scss">
.MyDiv {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    background-image: url($VUE_APP_CDN+"/MyImg.png");
}
</style>
```

or in a .scss file:

```
.MyDiv {
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    background-image: url($VUE_APP_CDN+"/MyImg.png");
}
```

from https://www.matt-helps.com/post/expose-env-variables-vue-cli-sass/

Comment: This works fine for scss files inside vue components. But I'm using Vuetify and it's variables.scss file (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/) and there is just not working. I get SassError: Undefined variable. And ideas?

Comment: Note on this all depends on your version of loader you're using.  For example in v8 you need to use `prependData` instead of `data`

Comment: Also if you're having issues make sure if you're using `scss` that you use `scss` instead of `sass` (or just add them both) @dari0h

Answer (score 1):

Important (in Vue 4 and likely Vue 3+ as well!): I set VUE_APP_VAR but could NOT see it by console logging process and opening the env object. I could see it by logging or referencing process.env.VUE_APP_VAR. I'm not sure why this is but be aware that you have to access the variable directly!

Comment: had the same issue -> in my case it was due to the fact, that i placed the .env file in the /src folder and not in the project root folder!

Answer (score 1):

if you're using Laravel with Vue and Webpack, you could try putting a prefix of `MIX_` onto your .env variables

i.e.:

```
MIX_SPACESHIP="U.S.S. Enterprise"
```

then pull that into a vue component via:

```
process.env.MIX_SPACESHIP
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using Vue CLI 3 and the webpack-simple install, [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52389695/10048675) did work for me however I wasn't keen on adding my environment variables to my `webpack.config.js` as I wanted to commit it to GitHub. Instead I  installed the [dotenv-webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv-webpack) plugin and this appears to load environment variables fine from a `.env` file at the root of the project without the need to prepend `VUE_APP_` to the environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Running multiple builds with different `.env` files**

In my app I wanted to have multiple production builds, one for a web app, and another for a browser extension.

In my experience, changing [build modes](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html) can have side effects as other parts of the build process can rely on being in `production` for example, so here's another way to provide a custom env file ([based on @GrayedFox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53704278/827129)):

#### package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "build:custom": "VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH=$PWD/vue.config.custom.js vue-cli-service build",
  }
}
```

#### vue.config.custom.js

```js
// install `dotenv` with `yarn add -D dotenv`
const webpack = require("webpack");
require("dotenv").config({ override: true, path: "./.env.custom" });

module.exports = {
  plugins: [new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({ ...process.env })],
};
```

Note 1: `VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH` [swaps out the config from the default of `vue.config.js`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52132611/827129), so any settings set in there will not apply for the `custom` build.

Note 2: this will load `.env.production` before `.env.custom`, so if you don't want any of the environment variables set in `.env.production` in your `custom` build, you'll want to set those to a blank string in `.env.custom`.

Note 3: [If you don't set `override: true` then environment variables in `.env.production` will take precedence over `.env.custom`](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#override).

Note 4: If you are looking to have multiple different builds using `vue-cli`, [the `--skip-plugins` option is very useful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55559575/827129).

Answer (score 0):

I am having same problem in vuecli@5. Trying to solve by reading official doc but can't get proper solution. After long time i got solution and it works fine.

1. Create .env file on root dir.  **touch .env**
2. Set value on it i.e APP_NAME=name
3. vue.config.js file past it **process.env.VUE_APP_VERSION = require('./package.json').version**
4. Log to any method **console.log(process.env.APP_NAME);**

Answer (score -1):

**just install this **

```
npm install -g @vue/cli
```

at your project
**it is worked with me**