# Specify a vue-cli vue.config.js location

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli, vue-cli-3

I have a `vue.config.js` file in my project's base directory.  I'd like to move this next to my other config files in a `/config/` folder.

How can I specify the new location of this file for `vue-cli`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The environment variable [`VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/6010eb2/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js#L262) specifies the **absolute** path to `vue.config.js`. Relative paths for this variable fail on macOS (and probably other platforms).

*Example on command line:*

```
$ VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH=$PWD/config/vue.config.js npm run build
```

*Or in `package.json`:*

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "VUE_CLI_SERVICE_CONFIG_PATH=$PWD/config/vue.config.js vue-cli-service build"
  }
}
```

Comment: 3years after, despite the "warning" on Github, this still works, and just helped me. Thanks tony!