# Disable PWA plugin in Vue CLI 3

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I'm having some issues with caching my files using the default service worker that comes with VueCLI 3. I would prefer to just use the default browser caching mechanism, but can't seem to disable the PWA plugin as its not in the `vue.config.js` file. Passing a blank object to the `pwa` option doesn't work either as the object is merged and not overwritten.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I resolved this by doing the following:

1. Removing the `registerServiceWorker.js` file
2. removing the import of `registerServiceWorker.js` from `main.js`.
3. removing the `PWA` plugin from the `devDependencies` in `package.json`.

Comment: I found that I also had to remove the `manifest.json` file, usually located in the /public directory.

Comment: Hello, after following this three step, the service worker cache just won't go away, any hint on how to blow that away on the client side?

Comment: and remove `register-service-worker` in `package.json` `dependencies`

Answer (score 15):

Vue enabled a method to disable pwa for certain builds in version 4. Now you can add `--skip-plugins pluginname` during your build. This one worked for me just fine:

```
 npx vue-cli-service build --skip-plugins pwa,workbox
```

Ref: https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#skipping-plugins

Answer (score 10):

There is an open but accepted proposal to add this to the core functionality: 
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/3830

**EDIT:**

Via **command line**:
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/cli-service.html#skipping-plugins

`npx vue-cli-service build --skip-plugins pwa,workbox`

Via **vue.config.j**s:

```js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.plugins.delete('pwa');
    config.plugins.delete('workbox');
  }
}
```