# Vue webpack environment variables configuration

Tags: vue.js, webpack, environment-variables

I am new to vue in general and i am trying to configure some environment variables for some projects of mine so i can do some tests with cookies but apperently i ran the simple webpack configurations when creating these projects, therefore i dont have access to the config directory to edit said variables.

I created a vue.config.js file and used the following lines:

```
module.exports = {
     publicPath: 'myAppName'
 }
```

However if i run it on development mode, or simply use npm run serve my app runs at  "http://localhost:8080/myAppName" instead of simply "myAppName".

How do i correctly configure my environment variables for my projects without having to start over from scratch? I am using vueCli 3 btw.

I tried following these examples but none have worked:
[Using Environment Variables with Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828904/using-environment-variables-with-vue-js)

I also have .env file and a .env.development file but i am not sure what to add to it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: oh, hey. yeah actually.
You have to create a config file and add URL:"mySite".
then go to your windows bin config files and add the ip address you want it to run