# How to hide secrets from client-side code using environment variables?

Tags: node.js, vue-cli-3

I am using Vue-CLI and *trying to hide certain "secrets" from the client-side code* using environment variables.

**Why do I get an `undefined` in console?**

Root file: `.env.development`

```
NODE_ENV=development
SECRET_WORD=foo
```

app file: `src/components/example.vue`

```
export default {
  created() {
    console.log(process.env.SECRET_WORD)
  },
...snip...
```

Now, if I do `VUE_APP_SECRET_WORD=foo` with `process.env.VUE_APP_SECRET_WORD` it works, but I don't want to display secrets statically like that.

Comment: I think this was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828904/using-environment-variables-with-vue-js)

Comment: yes but the answer there seems to say that it will transmit secrets to client side code.

Comment: Update: OK, I understand now. I need to go to my server's settings and input the secrets there...and THEN I can reference the process.env secrets from the client side code.