# Vue.js: load js file based on environment

Tags: vue.js

I have some js file which is generated by aws cognito, and its content is different based on environment.
As I should not modify it manually, so vue's environment variables may not work for me.

How should I dynamically load the js file based on the environment?
I use following command to run my server on local

> vue-cli-service serve --mode=dev

I located the file under /environment/dev/aws-exports.js

```
const awsmobile = {
    "aws_project_region": "ap-northeast-1",
    ... some more json...
};
export default awsmobile;
```

and load in the main.js

```
import config from "./environment/dev/aws-exports"
Amplify.configure(config);
```

How should I modify my code so that it can load it based on --mode?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use vue cli's `mode` for the conditional loading and not `NODE_ENV`?

Comment: use this link it might help [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50828904/using-environment-variables-with-vue-js)

Comment: @DigitalDrifter if mode cannot be used, I may use NODE_ENV and doing if else, but I would like to see are there any clearer way

Comment: @PallavChanana I have read that before and it seem not what i am looking for

Comment: Here is a nice article, maybe it will help you: https://rangle.io/blog/custom-build-modes-with-vue-cli-3/

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but I'll try to help:

To dynamically load the js file based on the environment you can create a `function` that returns an `import`:

```js
function getConfig(mode) {
  return import(`./environment/${mode}/aws-exports`)  // import returns a Promise
}
```

**Note**: remember that import is a Promise so you might need to `await` it.