# asp.net core environment variable not passing to vuejs config

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to pass environment vairable setup inside asp.net core (kesterl) to vuejs
My launchsettings is like

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44323/",
      "sslPort": 44323
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "BEAPI_URL": "http://localhost:4000/api/v1",
        "VUE_BEAPI_URL": "http://localhost:4000/api/v1"
      }
    },    
  }
}
```

and my vuejs config is as following

```
export default {
    // apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1'    
    apiUrl: process.env.VUE_BEAPI_URL
    
}
```

Anyone help like my scenario
Other then this my vuejs app is working fine under kesterl

Comment: What version of vue.js you are using? May be you need to add the Prefix VUE_APP_  to ENVs to make them available in your vue.js application. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50828904/83039

Comment: I have tried adding VUE_APP_ suffix but no effect. vuejs version is 2.6.12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following settings have worked
kesterl launchsetting (for environment variable name reference)

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:44323/",
      "sslPort": 44323
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "VUE_APP_BEAPI_URL": "http://localhost:4000/api/v1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

vuejs config

```
export default {
    // apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4000/api/v1',
    apiUrl: process.env.VUE_APP_BEAPI_URL,
    access_token:''
}
```