# Uncaught ReferenceError: vm is not defined vue.js 2.0

Tags: vuejs2

I am using **Vue 2.0** and I have an error

> (Uncaught ReferenceError: vm is not defined)

when i use `vm.$data` or any other in console to check the properties. I have latest version of vue.js 2.2.4.

Comment: what is vm, have you assigned it somewhere?

Answer (score 15):

As mentioned by @Fiete the `vm` variable wont be available by default.

You need to define `vm` globally to access it from the console.

Something like this should work

```
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    a: 1
  },
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: {
    App
  }
});

global.vm = vm; //Define your app variable globally
```

Now you can use `vm.$data.PROPERTY` or `vm.PROPERTY`.

Comment: It's because of webpack packing of js files :) here is the more detailed answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416826/2842750

Answer (score 2):

The `vm` variable does not exists by default. And vuejs does not set that variable. If you want to debug your vuejs application I recommend the [vuejs Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd).

By opening the extension on your page you can select the component you want to debug. After that you can access the selected component by using the `$vm0` variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
let app = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')


global.vm = app;
```

in anywhere,

```
globalThis.vm.$subscribeTo...
```

Answer (score 0):

`vm` looks like referring to the Vue instance, then just use `this.$set` instead of `vm.$set`. (Worked on a project generated with @vue/cli)

Answer (score 0):

It's really old, but for me the issue was that $vm would become unavailable when I was not focused on the tab / had different tab open. I just had to re-focus on the tab for which the devtools was open and $vm would appear again.

If just re-focusing won't do the trick, sometimes it helps to roam around Vue devtools Components tab until you see $vm written along the component names.

[image]