# access predefined global varriable with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack

I try to use the [Blueimp Gallery](https://blueimp.github.io/Gallery/) in Webpack.
Blueimp gallery defines a global function `blueimp`. Usually, one can create a Gallery using var `x = blueimp.Gallery(...);`

However, when I am using webpack, the blueimp-object gets hidden from me.

I imported blueimp Gallery in my main JS file using:

`import 'blueimp-gallery/js/blueimp-gallery.min';
import 'blueimp-gallery/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css';`

when I try to access `blueimp`, e.g. with `console.log(blueimp);`, I get a:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: blueimp is not defined

I probably need some sort of loader of predefination, like I did with jQuery:

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery");
```

and in the webpack config js

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery"
        })
```

But no matter how I try to configure `require(anything blueimp);` and/or a ProvidePlugin, blueimp will not be visible.

What am I missing?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack) is totally **not** solving my problem. I am not creating own modules, I wanna use the module I did download via npm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access all the variables in the window. Try:

```
window.blueimp
```

Comment: Awesome!
Removing 
`import 'blueimp-gallery/js/blueimp-gallery.min';`
and adding 
`window.blueimp = require("blueimp-gallery/js/blueimp-gallery.min");`

while then accessing `window.blueimp()` instead of accessing `blueimp.Gallery()` did the trick!