# How to disable output of import of TypeScript class declaration

Tags: typescript

**Setup:**

I am writing TypeScript definitions for some other external API.  I have created the defs for a class like so:

```js
// external.d.ts
export declare class MyClass<Schema>{...}
```

I then create a script that is designed to work with this external API:

```js
// script.ts
import { MyClass } from './external.d.ts';

const myObject = new MyClass<{}>();
```

My generated JavaScript looks like so:

```
// script.js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var external_1 = require("./external");
var myObject = new external_1.MyClass();
```

**Question:**

How can I get my output to look like this (no `require()` of the external):

```
// script.js
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var myObject = new MyClass();
```

For that matter, how can I get rid of the `Object.define...` output, too:

```
// script.js
var myObject = new MyClass();
```

Comment: `import` presupposes a module system. `require` (`--module commonjs`) is what typescript emits by default. If you are trying to build a module based app into a global script, you can use various approaches such as UMD, and you can use other build tools like Rollup. And this has nothing to do with declaration files, it has to do with import and export.

Comment: I think also my confusion with "class" being JavaScript, not TypeScript, is a contributing factor. I'm not sure I understand why the "declare class" gets removed from ```script.ts``` but not when it's imported.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

For some reason my tsconfig.json excluded "*.d.ts" in my "src" folder. That issue, combined with declaring globals in an ambient context solved my issue completely. I am able to reference globals and types without importing and my scripts compile without the extra stuff.

The discussion with @aluan-haddad as well as this provided the words necessary to figure this out:

[TypeScript how to declare global variable in every file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47794338/typescript-how-to-declare-global-variable-in-every-file)

So now my TypeScript can look as simple as this:

```js
// script.ts
interface MySchema{...};

const myObject = new MyClass<MySchema>();
```

...and my JS is just like I want it:

```js
// script.js
var myObject = new MyClass();
```

**PREVIOUSLY:**

I replaced `export declare class` with an interface and declared my class in `script.js`:

```js
// script.ts
import { MyInterface } from './external.d.ts';

declare class MyClass {
  constructor();
}

const myObject = new MyClass() as MyInterface<{}>;
```

...and it outputs as desired.  There may be a better way than a brute force casting, however.

Comment: This is a radical behavior change, due to a lack of explicit TypeScript configuration, you should not do this lightly. The reason this happens is that imports that are only used in _type_ position are elided by the compiler. Ultimately, the question is this: Is there a file `./external.js` that exports anything at all? If `MyClass` is a global variable, then your mistake is exporting it

Comment: No there is no ```external.js```, only the ```.d.ts```.  I'm writing the defs for an external API using their documentation.  My generated output will then get merged into the external application whose global context includes ```MyClass``` among others.

Comment: Then you are writing your definitions incorrectly and consuming them incorrectly. If you are writing definitions for globals, your definitions need to be global. That means that you neither import them nor export them.

Comment: Is it possible to put ```declare const/class Whatever``` in another file and use it in ```script.ts```? Or do you mean something else by "global definition"?

Comment: That's what I mean, yes. Just have a file with `declare class X {}` Having `import` or `export` in a file completely changes its meaning from script to module. And, most importantly, since you are trying to write global code, in your `tsconfig.json` specify `"module": "none"` under `"compilerOptions"` so that the compiler will not let you use `import`/`export`. That's really worth doing. Otherwise you are going to go crazy.