# Using CommonsChunkPlugin without always needing to define webpackJsonp?

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2, dexie

I have a project that makes use of a large bundle ([dexie.js](http://dexie.org/) not that it's important to this question), that I'd like to 'split out' into it's own bundle that I can include manually, because it's only needed in a few of my entry point scripts.

Just so that you know: my webpack config uses multiple modules, with multiple (6) entry points, so this is a cut-down sample of my `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
entry: {
    'js/contentscript.js' : './js/contentscript.js',
    'js/background.js'    : './js/background.js',
    'js/popup.js'         : './js/popup.js',
    'js/options.js'       : './js/options.js',
},
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'), 
    filename: "[name]"
},
plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "dexie",
        filename: "js/dexie.js",
        minChunks: function (module) {
            // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
            return module.context && module.context.includes("node_modules/dexie");
        }
    }),
    ... // other non relevant plugins here
]
}
```

The problem is that I have no typical 'vendor' nor 'common' requirement, like many other projects to. It's *only* in a few cases that I want to include the `js/dexie.js` bundle.

eg. in `options.html`, I have this:

```
<script src="js/dexie.js"></script>
<script src="js/options.js"></script>
```

...but I do not want it to be used for `popup.html`, which I want to keep as this:

```
<script src="js/popup.js"></script>
```

And since this is also a WebExtensions project, I *definitely* don't want my content scripts to need it!

The problem is, that when I open popup.js, I get the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: webpackJsonp is not defined`.

Is there any way  -- *without splitting this into more webpack modules* -- so that the `CommonsChunkPlugin` will play nice with the entry points so that only the ones I want are affected by it?

The only solution I can think of, is to make another `CommonsChunkPlugin` that acts in the way that 'vendor' and 'common' is typically used. That is:

```
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "dexie",
        filename: "js/dexie.js",
        minChunks: function (module) {
            // this assumes your vendor imports exist in the node_modules directory
            return module.context && module.context.includes("node_modules/dexie");
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: "manifest",
        filename: "js/manifest.js",
        minChunks: Infinity
    }),
```

Unfortunately, this means I need to include `js/manifest.js` in *all* my scripts, and since this is a WebExtension, then that means I have to inject it into each content page...IMHO this is a terrible solution.

Any ideas on how to improve this? Am I using `CommonsChunkPlugin` incorrectly? Is there a better module I should be using? (I'm actually still coming to grips with webpack!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled across this excellent answer by @prograhammer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416826/125525

In it he made reference to the [Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) plugin, which I'd not heard of before, and it neatly solves my problems. This is the description from the webpack site:

> For example, to include jQuery from a CDN instead of bundling it:
>
> index.html
>
> ```
> <script
>   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"
>   integrity="sha256-slogkvB1K3VOkzAI8QITxV3VzpOnkeNVsKvtkYLMjfk="
>   crossorigin="anonymous">
> </script>
> ```
>
> webpack.config.js
>
> ```
> externals: {
>   jquery: 'jQuery'
> }
> ```
>
> This leaves any dependent modules unchanged, i.e. the code shown below
>   will still work:
>
> ```
> import $ from 'jquery';
>
> $('.my-element').animate(...);
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using 'js/xxx.js' as an entry name is not a good way.
If your options.js need dexie.js and popup.js do not need it.
You can try to change files like below.

webpack.config.js

```
entry: {
    'vendor' : ['dexie'],
    'contentscript' : './js/contentscript.js',
    'background'    : './js/background.js',
    'popup'         : './js/popup.js',
    'options'       : './js/options.js',
},
resolve: {
    alias: {
        'dexie':'...'
    }
},
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: "vendor",
    minChunks: Infinity
}),
```

Like I said before, CommonChunksPlugin will automatically help u extract common dependencies, in this case you dont need write a function of minChunks to indicate dependencies.

options.html

```
<script src="js/vendor.js"></script>
<script src="js/options.js"></script>
```

popup.html

```
<script src="js/popup.js"></script>
```

Comment: I want to use CommonChunksPlugin for *some* files, without affecting the others.

Comment: CommonChunksPlugin will automatically help u extract common dependencies.You only need declare one new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin.

Comment: You need to read my question again carefully. I outline the problem very clearly.