# Webpack - How to load non module scripts into global scope | window

Tags: webpack, webpack-3

so i have a few vendor files that i need to run from window scoped (it's a bunch of window scoped functions) plus i have some polyfills that i would like to bundle into the vendor bundle as well.

So i tried something like this:

```
new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
    name: 'vendor',
    filename: 'js/vendor.min.js',
    minChunks: Infinity,
})

entry: {
    'vendor' : ['./vendor.js', './vendor2.js', './polyfills.js']
}
```

Now when i run my webpack build it does generate my vendor bundle but it's all wrapped in a webpackJsonP wrapper so the functions are not accessible on the window scope.

I've also looked at using something like the ProvidePlugin but i couldn't make that work at all since i don't have a defined name like jQuery where everything is mapped under.

Is this even possible in webpack?

Comment: Can you name one vendor for example?

Comment: We for example use IBM Coremetrics for analytics purposes

Comment: Is this library/file public, do you have a link?
How do you mean it doesn't have a name like jQuery? If you load one of your vendor scripts, the regular way, in a browser, how does it register itself globally on windows?

Comment: ... on  `window`

Comment: Here is a link: https://libs.coremetrics.com/eluminate.js this is one example i have a few more of these libraries. What I mean with it&#39;s not like jquery is that it&#39;s not namespaced or wrapped in one function like $. All functions are on a global scope exposed to the window scope. Hope that make sense, oh and you might have to run that file through a beautifier. And it doesn't expose itself like: window.funcionName unfortunately otherwise it would be easy.

Comment: Your best choice I guess, would be to use a `script-loader` which registers everything in the global namsespace. take a look [here](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules#script-loader).

You can use a config for `script-loader` or use it inline with `import exec from 'script-loader!./eluminate.js';`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Use the script-loader plugin:**

If you want the whole script to register in the global namespace you have to use [script-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader). This is not recommend, as it breaks the sense of modules ;-)
But if there is no other way:

```
npm install --save-dev script-loader
```

[Webpack docs](https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/shimming-modules#script-loader)

> This loader evaluates code in the global context, just like you would
>   add the code into a script tag. In this mode every normal library
>   should work. require, module, etc. are undefined.
>
> Note: The file is added as string to the bundle. It is not minimized
>   by webpack, so use a minimized version. There is also no dev tool
>   support for libraries added by this loader.

Then in your entry.js file you could import it **inline**:

```
import  "script-loader!./eluminate.js"
```

**or via config:**

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /eluminate\.js$/,
        use: [ 'script-loader' ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**and in your entry.js**

```
import './eluminate.js';
```

As I said, it pollutes the global namespace:

[image]

Comment: Cool thanks for the answer I'm going to try this and report back soon!

Comment: I don't know how you got this to work, but i keep getting: [Script Loader] ReferenceError: CM_DDX is not defined. i see most properties in the window scope now so that's a step but it keeps falling on that error. And i see in your screenshot it is there. I added this in my entry file: import "script-loader!./coremetrics/eluminate"; and i had to exclude that specific bundle from my babel task otherwise it was completely failing.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't use `babel` for transpiling, but `TypeScript`. I just installed the `script-loader` package and did it the inline way: `import  "script-loader!./eluminate.js"`. That's all.

Comment: Cool, thabks anyways! I'll go setup a minimal setup and give that some test runs I am at least on the right track. I appreciate it!

Comment: Put it on github, perhaps we can take a look at your minimal setup together then...

Comment: I used this approach but unfortunately script-loader uses eval, and we've got CSP configured to block eval, which makes this a very difficult thing to achieve.

Comment: @AntonyO'Neill Fell free to create a CSP compliant `script-loader` plugin ;.-)

Comment: Haha! I'm not sure if that's possible... I'm trying a different approach now, using a query parameter on the import to load the JS as a file and load it in a script tag in HTML.

Answer (score 7):

[script-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader) should-not be used anymore. You can use [raw-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader) instead:

```
npm install --save-dev raw-loader
```

And:

```
import('!!raw-loader!./nonModuleScript.js').then(rawModule => eval.call(null, rawModule.default));
```

I'm using `!!` before `raw-loader` because I'm [in the case described](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/raw-loader#inline) in the documentation:

> *Adding `!!` to a request will disable all loaders specified in the configuration*

Comment: This is now deprecated. See https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/ instead

Answer (score 3):

Both above solutions will have issues when the site is enforcing some content-security-policy(CSP) rules due to use of [unsafe eval expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src#Unsafe_eval_expressions), which is absolutely a good thing. (always treat security as first-class citizen in web ;))

Alternative solutions i have found so far are, assuming you are also working on a legacy codebase and having this kind of need

For `UMD` modules, consider [import-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/), an example

```
 test: require.resolve('jquery'),
 use: {
      loader: 'imports-loader',
      options: {
        wrapper: {
          thisArg: 'window',
          args: {
            module: false,
            exports: false,
            define: false,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

For `CJS` modules export to global namespace, consider [expose-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/).

Also if you have time, give [webpack shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/) a read.