# script-loader alternative for webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-loader, unsafe-eval

When bundling web app using webpack, i need to register some 3rd party scripts into global(i.e. `window`) namespace, [script-loader](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/script-loader/) seems designed for this [Webpack - How to load non module scripts into global scope | window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998102/webpack-how-to-load-non-module-scripts-into-global-scope-window).

However, there is a big downside of it, the generated code uses `eval.call` which is not compliant with most CSP security guidelines and thus strongly discouraged to use it in production. Is there any alternative webpack loader that i can use to achieve the same purpose without XSS vulnerabilities?

<sub>Also the GitHub project https://github.com/webpack-contrib/script-loader is already archived</sub>

Answer (score 0):

So far this looks like the best solution, but it's tedious:

https://webpack.js.org/loaders/imports-loader/

Basically you need to know what side-effect each script is performing, and imports-loader gives you ways to make them happen. For example, you can wrap the script in a function call that binds `this` to the global `window` object.

It would be nice if we could somehow just have the scripts run in order, but I also see how that would be difficult in Webpack without `eval`, which is the problem.