# Accessing global variable after webpack build

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Let I have a file index.js with content

```
var a = 1;
```

I have index.html file which include index.js using `<script>` tag.
When I open index.html page in browser, then the `a` variable can be accessed directly in browser console. Because `a` have global scope and it is global variable.

Now I am using npm and webpack. 
My package.json file content is

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack"
},
```

and webpack.config.js file content is

```
module.exports = {
entry: './index.js',
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
}
```

Now I run npm build then new file is created in dist folder named bundle.js.

Now I replace index.js from `script` tag of index.html file with dist/bundle.js .

Now I run index.html in browser, but variable `a` is no longer access in browser console directly. It is not a global variable now.

My question is : 
Is there a way by which we can access variable `a` globally just like we access initially?

I have not found exact answer on internet. I found a loader [expose-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/expose-loader/) but it also can't solve my problem.

Comment: what do you need the global var for ? I mean what is the use case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define global variable with webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack)

Comment: @Luillyfe I have old writtten many js file for a website which are included in html by script tag. Many function and variable are globally define, so that they can access by other included javascript file.

Comment: Buy after the build what you need for ? Before the build you can still access the var, Right?

Comment: @Luillyfe I want to minify js file by using UglifyJsPlugin

Comment: Webpack do that for you, check it out to the docs. https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#minification. try this command, webpack  --mode 'production'

Comment: I know this, but global variable and function will not accessed directly

Comment: how you solve this, I also got an unworking config

Answer (score 11):

When webpack bundles your javascript it wraps all of your individual files/modules in functions so they are no longer run in the global scope, therefore if you want to make a variable global you have to explicitly set it on the window object, i.e.

```
window.a = 1;
```

This will make `a` accessible from the browser console in `index.html`.

Comment: I have many variable and functions defined globally in many files. By this way I have to change at many places of all javascript file. Is there any simple way

Comment: Don't know why I didn't think of this. ‍♂️ Sometimes the best answers are the simplest and most obvious. Thank you! :)