# Preserve a single JavaScript variable name through Webpack minification

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-4

The code I've created is being added to a larger code base that is expecting a particular variable name. I'd like to be able to minify my code while maintain a single variables full name.

I'm aware of the `window["myVar"]` trick however the larger code base is expecting the value of `myVar` to be a assigned to a particular value calculated by my code.

Comment: You don't want to create a solution like this, it will be a black box changing some kind of state in minified code, which is very hard to debug. Alternatively you can emit an event which other code can subscribe to.

Comment: This question has an answer that may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack