# Preserve a variable name in .js after Webpack 4 build

Tags: javascript, webpack-4, bundling-and-minification

Easy question. In my .js code, inside a module, I had something like:

```
var MyVar = MyVar || 'anyOtherValue'
```

When Webpack creates the 'Build" it covnerts it to:

```
var a = a || 'anyOtherValue'
```

THE PROBLEM with that is that **my HTML is converted by another team into .jsp** for a MPA. In each page the **backend team injects a Global variable (*MyVar*)** which will be used by the javascript if present:

**page1.jsp**

```
<script>
   var myVar="New Value";
</script>
```

**Question is**: ¿How can I tell Webpack to 'leave' myVar variable with its current name instead of transforming it?

I did following workaround which seems awful to the eyes, though it works:

```
window.myVar = window.myVar || 'someValue';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your solution is actually a proper one. As webpack is working with modules, it has no idea that this specific variable should be accessed / taken from outside.   
You can read more about this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack