# Module name "jquery" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require

Tags: javascript, typescript, requirejs

I am trying to migrate my Javascript files to Typescript files, however I am stuck when I try to use the transpiled javascript file in html page and get the following error:

```
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
at makeError (require.min.js:1)
at Object.s [as require] (require.min.js:1)
at requirejs (require.min.js:1)
at helloworld.js:4
```

My Typescript file

```
import * as $ from "jquery";

export class Loading {
  public showLoadingModal(msg?: string) {
    if (msg === undefined) {
  msg = "Loading ...";
    }
    $("#dialog1 label").html(msg);
    //$('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
  }

  public hideLoadingModal() {
    // $('#pleaseWaitDialog').modal('hide');
  }

  public keepOpenLoadingModal() {
    $("#dialog1").on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
      return false;
    });
    this.showLoadingModal();
  }
}
```

Transpiled Javascript file

```
"use strict";
exports.__esModule = true;
exports.Loading = void 0;
var $ = require("jquery");
var Loading = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Loading() {
    }
    Loading.prototype.showLoadingModal = function (msg) {
        if (msg === undefined) {
            msg = "Loading ...";
        }
        $("#dialog1 label").html(msg);
        //$('#dialog1').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
    };
    Loading.prototype.hideLoadingModal = function () {
        // $('#dialog1').modal('hide');
    };
    Loading.prototype.keepOpenLoadingModal = function () {
        $("#dialog1").on("hide.bs.modal", function () {
            return false;
        });
        this.showLoadingModal();
    };
    return Loading;
}());
exports.Loading = Loading;
```

I have loaded the Jquery from CDN like below

```
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        <base href="/" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />
    
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
        <script>
          var exports = {};
        </script>
        <script src="helloworld.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h3 class="text-center mt-2 mb-2">Demo</h3>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I also tried loading the jquery with below code but no luck

````
      var exports = {};
      requirejs.config({
        baseUrl: "/js/lib",
        paths: {
          jquery: "jquery.min",
        },
      });
      requirejs(["jquery"], function (jquery) {
        console.log(jquery); // OK
      });
    </script>```
Can you please help me resolve the error, I know this is very first step in my migration journey and I am badly stuck here, any help is much appreciated.
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've transpiled the code from TypeScript to CommonJS.

Browsers don't support the CommonJS module system, they only support the ECMAScript module system.

The `requirejs` library you use only supports the AMD module system.

---

You should fix this at the point you transpile the code. You need to target browsers. This is most commonly done using [Webpack which has a loader for TypeScript modules](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/).

---

Aside: If you're `import`ing (and thus bundling) jQuery then you should not also load it from a CDN.

Comment: thanks for your reply.

If I configure transpile part with webpack as suggested by you, then how the dependencies will be taken care for Jquery or Bootstrap.js? will it be taken care by webback itself?

Comment: You `import`ed jQuery so jQuery will be included in the bundle produced by Webpack.

Comment: Great, So it means where I need to consume the bundle file there I need not to worry about the query or Bootstrap.js.
Also will it be possible if I can create separate js files for each ts file? when I do build from webpack project or it will be a single bundle containing all the ts files?

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply, I will give it a try and may bother if I stuck.

Comment: One more help/query, suppose if I have bundle created with the help of the webpack and I have loaded the bundle.js file in html page. Now if I need to use the classes created from that bundle.js file then how it needs to be referred?
Suppose if I have a class ShowLoading in ShowLoading.ts file and I would like to use it out of that bundle.js.

Comment: Generally: Don't. Let the top of the bundle be the entry point. Don't try to create globals which are accessible outside it. That said: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416826/19068

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236909/discussion-between-yashpal-s-and-quentin).