# Is there a way to assign the content of a file to a specific variable using webpack?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Is there a way to assign the file contents directly to a variable/method without webpack generating an additional variable?

Currently webpack does something like this:

**index.js**

```js
import scss from './styles.scss';
console.log(scss);
```

**output.js (actual)**

```js
const styles = '...';
console.log(styles);
```

I want webpack to return the content of the `styles.scss` file directly to the console.log() method in the output without adding `styles` variable.

**output.js (expected)**

```js
console.log('...');
```

I'm currently using my custom loader for reading `.scss` files:

**css-loader.js**

```js
const sass = require('sass');

module.exports = function(source) {
    const result = sass.compile(this.resourcePath);

    return 'export default `\n' + result.css + '\n`';
};
```

I know there is a way to do this using the `require()` function but it generates a lot of extra code coming from webpack. Is there any other better way to do it?

Comment: Note sure what you're trying to do exactly but have you considered using `fs/promises.readFilePath`? https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/fs.html#fspromisesreadfilepath-options

Comment: The file is imported correctly, I have access to its contents, so everything is ok with it. The problem is that webpack in the `output.js` file first assigns me the contents of the imported file to a variable that it generates itself. And I want it to be immediately assigned to the variable I specified, which is in a different scope (and not at the top of the code, where `import` is used). @Webber

Comment: So it's really a scoping issue then. So there's no real requirement to not wanting webpacks default behaviour. Webpack has a few ways how to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack

Comment: Honestly, I didn't think of using the `webpack.DefinePlugin` method in that way (to assign the contents of the file as a global variable and then use it) but it works perfectly. Thank you! btw Sorry but I'm new to Stackoverflow and from what I've read you probably need to write this comment as an answer so I can accept it. @Webber

Comment: Glad it helped you. Added an answer @exec1990

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it's really a scoping issue. So there's no real requirement to not wanting webpacks default behaviour.

Webpack has a few ways how to do that. See this other answer for how to [define a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack), which is Webpacks way of doing what you want to do.