# Building a TypeScript library, some setbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, es6-modules

I want to build a TypeScript library to handle a recurring need across multiple non-node servers (websites). I want to be able to simply have one minified JS file as a result that contains all the code and the required modules (like a CDN: [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.1.2/axios.min.js)).

My webpack config:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "bundle": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/generators": "^2.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.1.2",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.1",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.7.4"
  }
}
```

My ts config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noImplicitThis": false,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "./lib/**/*"
  ]
}
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
module
-dist/
-lib/
--types/
--- ** I have here different types
--services/
--- ** I expect to have services here, empty for now
--index.ts
-node_modules/
-package.json
-package-lock.json
-tsconfig.json
-webpack.config.js
```

My index.ts:

```
import {type1} from './types/type1';
import {type2} from './types/type2';
....
   
export default class init{

 private readonly axios: object;
  constructor() {
    this.axios = require('axios').default;
    this.init();
  }

  init(){
    console.log('loaded')
    console.log(this.axios)
  }
}
```

After I run webpack, I include the resulting main.js in my index.html to test. I expect to have the library available. But the class init() is never defined..I tried exporting a function instead, or not exporting anything and it did not work. Can someone shed some light on the process ?

Comment: How does the build file `main.js` look like?

Comment: "*I expect to have the library available*" - how did you import it? Did you `import init from 'main.js'`?

Comment: @Terry it is a long minified string

```!function(e,t){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof ...```

Comment: @Bergi no I did not. I am trying to have the library available simply with the the script tag..just like a CDN

Comment: @fennec Then you will need to instruct the compiler/bundler to expose the default export of your entry point module as a global variable.

Comment: @Bergi is that how those minified CDNs are created ? I would much rather go with the convention. How would I do that with webpack ?

Comment: @fennec That has nothing to do with a CDN, that's just how libraries work that you include as a script. There's also libraries (both CDN-provided and not) that are ES6 modules which need to be `import`ed. (If you ask me, this is superior, but not everyone seems to be ready for this).

Comment: @fennec See https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/ and in particular https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputlibrary

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack