Unable to reference NPM package globally
webpack.config.js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  entry: '/src/index.js',

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..','..', 'public_html', 'dist', 'webpack'),

    filename: 'dist.js',
  },
  
  plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
       $: 'jquery',
     }),
   ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, 
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      },
    ],
  },

  devtool: 'source-map',
};

index.js
var _ = require('lodash');
var $ = require('jquery');

test.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Lodash</title>
    <script src="/dist/webpack/dist.js"></script>
    <script defer type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            const shuffled = _.shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
            console.log('Shuffled array:', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
            document.getElementById("parentID").innerHTML+= "shuffled array: " + shuffled + '<br>';

             $(document).ready(function() {}
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="parentID"><br></div>
</body>
</html>


error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I am implementing NPM and webpack and currently need to reference it from HTML pages like test.html. I am just looking to bundle and reference packages from NPM in this way.
The lodash portion of this works properly.
home\
|--> public_html\
|-----> test.hml
|-----> dist
|-------> webpack\
|---------> dist.js
|--> san_mounted\
|-----> npm\
|--------> src\
|-----------> index.js
|--------> webpack.config.js
|--------> package-lock.json
|--------> package.json
|--------> node-modules\


For the record I did try original jQuery and ran into the same issue, I mentioned that in the question @ggorlen

You have to import jQuery and make it globally accessible to use it in a script tag. Webpack creates module-like code. Only the exported variables are accessible through imports. You can't access local variables that aren't exported. You can export the variables and import it in your scripts with ES modules. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script/type

@jabaa isn't that the purpose of the index.js? To make it accessible globally?

No, that's not the purpose of the index.js. Today, the index.js is usually the entry point to a module or package. 15 years ago the situation was different, but that was long before Webpack was used.

@jabaa interesting. I guess im confused why lodash works fine with my setup. That link you provided it useful, but do you have an example of using jQuery how I'm trying?

window.$ = $; makes it globally available. I guess, the lodash import does it internally.

This question is similar to: What is the correct way to define global variable in ES6 modules?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This is better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37656592/define-global-variable-with-webpack#40416826

@jabaa interesting, thanks for the links. Is it bad practice to global scope the packages in the index.js like this? It appears to work
`var zxcvbn = require('zxcvbn');
window.zxcvbn = zxcvbn;
var $ = require('jquery');
window.$ = $;`
after doing so I can succeuflly reference them in my html console.log(zxcvbn('Tr0ub4dour&3'));

Yes, that's bad practice and the reason why the IIFE pattern was used and third-party module systems were developed 20 years ago and a module system made it into the JavaScript standard 8 years ago. It looks like you write JavaScript and HTML code from before 2016. Here you can read many opinions that it's bad practice and examples and reasons why it's bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8862665/what-does-it-mean-global-namespace-would-be-polluted

Unrelated to your question: $(document).ready(function() {} also looks like JavaScript before 2016. I only work with jQuery in very old legacy code, usually with the goal to remove jQuery. Today, most web developers wouldn't use it anymore.

@jabaa this is a legacy web app I am trying to bring up to speed somewhat by implementing npm, etc. long way to go. Putting them in global scope is the only way I have been able to get it working so far. The other solutions aren't working for me at the moment.

@jabaa yes I agree, it is out of date and only using it to prove this out.
